# Custom feature extraction class in scikit-learn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-extraction, text-classification, supervised-learning

I am very beginner to the scikit-learn .I am working on some classification problem for which I have to build some custom feature extraction class or method to find the features for the training data. 
I have made my custom feature extraction class as explain in this [link](https://www.dreisbach.us/blog/building-scikit-learn-compatible-transformers/). When i run my code it shows me this error :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 248, in <module>
    pred = pipe.predict(X_test)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/metaestimators.py", line 54, in <lambda>
    out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 327, in predict
    return self.steps[-1][-1].predict(Xt)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 336, in predict
    scores = self.decision_function(X)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 317, in decision_function
    % (X.shape[1], n_features))
ValueError: X has 174 features per sample; expecting 443
```

Below is my code snippet , also i have given my full code. Please tell me where i am doing wrong and why , along with the suggestions so that my code will run without any error.

Code snippet :-
Here "y" is a list of all categories or labelled group ."corpus" is the list of all documents (data) , where each doc. is represented like a string."tfidf" and "lda" are my two functions from which i am generating my feature vector

```
y = [d[0] for d in doc_info_with_label] #length is no:ofsamples
corpus = [d[1] for d in doc_info_with_label]

class feature_extractor(TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self,*featurizers):
        self.featurizers = featurizers
    def fit(self,X,y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self,X):
        collection_features=[]
        for f in self.featurizers:
            collection_features.append(f(X))
        feature_vect=np.array(collection_features[0])
        if len(collection_features)>1:
            for i in range(1,len(collection_features)):
                feature_vect=np.concatenate((feature_vect,np.array(collection_features[i])),axis=1)
        #print feature_vect.shape
        return feature_vect


my_featurizer = feature_extractor(tfidf,lda)
X = my_featurizer.transform(corpus)
X_train , X_test , y_train , y_test = train_test_split(corpus,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=42)
pipe = make_pipeline(my_featurizer,svm.LinearSVC())
pipe.fit(X_train,y_train)
pred = pipe.predict(X_test)
print "Expected output\n"
print y_test
print "\n"
print "Output\n"
print pred
print "\n"
score = pipe.score(X_test,y_test)
print score
print "\n"
print metrics.confusion_matrix(pred,y_test)
```

full code :-

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#! /usr/bin/env python3
from gensim import corpora, models
import gensim
from operator import itemgetter
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import re
import codecs
import io
import math
from scipy import sparse
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline , Pipeline


reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
np.set_printoptions(threshold='nan')

suffixes = {
    1: ["ो", "े", "ू", "ु", "ी", "ि", "ा"],
    2: ["कर", "ाओ", "िए", "ाई", "ाए", "ने", "नी", "ना", "ते", "ीं", "ती", "ता", "ाँ", "ां", "ों", "ें"],
    3: ["ाकर", "ाइए", "ाईं", "ाया", "ेगी", "ेगा", "ोगी", "ोगे", "ाने", "ाना", "ाते", "ाती", "ाता", "तीं", "ाओं", "ाएं", "ुओं", "ुएं", "ुआं"],
    4: ["ाएगी", "ाएगा", "ाओगी", "ाओगे", "एंगी", "ेंगी", "एंगे", "ेंगे", "ूंगी", "ूंगा", "ातीं", "नाओं", "नाएं", "ताओं", "ताएं", "ियाँ", "ियों", "ियां"],
    5: ["ाएंगी", "ाएंगे", "ाऊंगी", "ाऊंगा", "ाइयाँ", "ाइयों", "ाइयां"],
}

categories=['A','C','D','E']
mappings={}
mappings['A']=1
mappings['C']=3
mappings['D']=4
mappings['E']=5

path='/home/priyansh/Downloads/ltrc/1055/'
train_data_path='/home/priyansh/Downloads/ltrc/extractor/clustering/four_class_devanagari/'
path1=train_data_path+"A/"
path2=train_data_path+"C/"
path3=train_data_path+"D/"
path4=train_data_path+"E/"
documents=[] #contains all doc filenames along with class labels
doc_info_with_label=[] #two tuple storage of doc info along with their respective labels

def hi_stem(word):
    for L in 5, 4, 3, 2, 1:
        if len(word) > L + 1:
            for suf in suffixes[L]:
                if word.endswith(suf):
                    return word[:-L]
    return word

def store_data(dir_path_list):
    for dir_path in dir_path_list:
        class_name = dir_path.split("/")[8]
        for filename in os.listdir(dir_path):
            if filename not in documents:
                documents.append(filename+"+"+str(mappings[class_name]))
            infilename=os.path.join(dir_path,filename)
            with codecs.open(infilename,'r','utf-8') as fl:
                string=''
                for line in fl:
                    for word in line.split():
                        if word!=" " or word!="\n":
                            string+=word+" "
            fl.close()
            temp=[]
            temp.append(class_name)
            temp.append(string)
            doc_info_with_label.append(tuple(temp))

path_list=[]
path_list.append(path1)
path_list.append(path2)
path_list.append(path3)
path_list.append(path4)
store_data(path_list)

y = [d[0] for d in doc_info_with_label] #length is no:ofsamples
corpus = [d[1] for d in doc_info_with_label]

class feature_extractor(TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self,*featurizers):
        self.featurizers = featurizers
    def fit(self,X,y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self,X):
        collection_features=[]
        for f in self.featurizers:
            collection_features.append(f(X))
        feature_vect=np.array(collection_features[0])
        if len(collection_features)>1:
            for i in range(1,len(collection_features)):
                feature_vect=np.concatenate((feature_vect,np.array(collection_features[i])),axis=1)
        #print feature_vect.shape
        return feature_vect

def tfidf_score(word,document_no,corpus_data):
    #print word
    my_word=word
    stopwords_path='/home/priyansh/Downloads/ltrc/extractor/'
    stop_words_filename='stopwords.txt'
    stopwords=[] #contain all stopwords
    with codecs.open(stopwords_path+stop_words_filename,'r','utf-8') as fl:
            for line in fl:
            for word in line.split():
                    stopwords.append(word)
    fl.close()
    document=corpus_data[document_no]
    #print document
    wordcount=0
    total=0
    temp = document.split()
    for i in temp:
        #print i
        if i not in stopwords:
            total+=1
            if i==my_word:
                #print my_word
                #print word
                wordcount+=1
    #print wordcount
    #print total
    tf = float(wordcount)/total
    #print tf
    #return tf(word,document)*idf(word,corpus_data)
    total_docs = len(corpus_data)
    count=0
    for doc in corpus_data:
        temp=[]
        temp = doc.split()
        for i in temp:
            if i==word:
                count+=1
                break
    total_docs_which_contains_the_words=count
    idf = math.log(total_docs/(1+total_docs_which_contains_the_words))
    return tf*idf


def tfidf(corpus_data):
    word_id_mapping={}
    cnt=0
    stopwords_path='/home/priyansh/Downloads/ltrc/extractor/'
    stop_words_filename='stopwords.txt'
    stopwords=[] #contain all stopwords
    with codecs.open(stopwords_path+stop_words_filename,'r','utf-8') as fl:
            for line in fl:
            for word in line.split():
                    stopwords.append(word)
    fl.close()
    unique_words_in_corpus={}
    count=0
    for data in corpus_data:
        corpus_id=count
        temp=[]
        temp=data.split()
        for word in temp:
            if word not in unique_words_in_corpus:
                unique_words_in_corpus[word]=corpus_id

        count+=1
    stopped_unique_words_in_corpus={}
    for word in unique_words_in_corpus:
        if word not in stopwords:
            stopped_unique_words_in_corpus[word]=unique_words_in_corpus[word]
            word_id_mapping[word]=cnt
            cnt+=1
    #print unique_words_in_corpus
    #print stopped_unique_words_in_corpus
    #print word_id_mapping
    feature_vect=[None]*len(corpus_data)
    #score_vect=[None]*cnt
    for i in range(0,len(corpus_data)):
        score_vect=[0]*cnt
        for word in stopped_unique_words_in_corpus:
            if i==stopped_unique_words_in_corpus[word]:
                #print word
                score=tfidf_score(word,i,corpus_data)
                #print score
                score_vect[word_id_mapping[word]]=score
        feature_vect[i]=score_vect
        return feature_vect

def lda(corpus_data):
    stopwords_path='/home/priyansh/Downloads/ltrc/extractor/'
    stop_words_filename='stopwords.txt'
    stopwords=[] #contain all stopwords
    with codecs.open(stopwords_path+stop_words_filename,'r','utf-8') as fl:
            for line in fl:
            for word in line.split():
                    stopwords.append(word)
    fl.close()
    texts=[]
    for data in corpus_data:
        #print data
        tokens=[]
        temp=[]
        stopped_tokens=[]
        temp = data.split()
        for word in temp:
            tokens.append(word)
        #print tokens
        for i in tokens:
            if i not in stopwords:
                stopped_tokens.append(i)
        stemmed_tokens=[]
        for token in stopped_tokens:
            stemmed_token = hi_stem(token)
            stemmed_tokens.append(stemmed_token)
        texts.append(stemmed_tokens)

    dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(texts)
    corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]
    num_topics=5
    ldamodel = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus, num_topics=num_topics, id2word = dictionary, passes=10)
    doc_topics=[]
    for doc_vector in corpus:
            doc_topics.append(ldamodel[doc_vector])


    for i in range(0,len(doc_topics)):
            doc_topics[i] = sorted(doc_topics[i],key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True)

    feature_vect=[]
    for i in doc_topics:
        prob_vect=[0]*num_topics
        #print i
        topic_num = i[0][0]
        topic_prob = i[0][1]
        prob_vect[topic_num]=topic_prob
        feature_vect.append(prob_vect)
        #print i
        #print feature_vect
        return feature_vect


my_featurizer = feature_extractor(tfidf,lda)
X = my_featurizer.transform(corpus)
X_train , X_test , y_train , y_test = train_test_split(corpus,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=42)
pipe = make_pipeline(my_featurizer,svm.LinearSVC())
pipe.fit(X_train,y_train)
pred = pipe.predict(X_test)
print "Expected output\n"
print y_test
print "\n"
print "Output\n"
print pred
print "\n"
score = pipe.score(X_test,y_test)
print score
print "\n"
print metrics.confusion_matrix(pred,y_test)
```

Comment: Make sure that `my_featurizer` returns same number of columns on both `X_train` and `X_test`.

Comment: That couldn't be possible i mean since i am using tfidf scores as one of features which are corpus based (different when no:of text documents i,e, X_test are different ) .So how i do this ?

Comment: All scikit estimators work on the same number of columns in train and test, so you need to find a way.

Comment: @Vivek thanks for ur help . I will try ...if u have any other suggestion plz tell me .

Comment: I did not go through the whole code, but if its calculating tfidf, then maybe look at the [TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) and its source code to see how it works keeping the columns same.

Comment: @VivekKumar i have solved the problem ...for that i have to remove the pipeline and just used my class to construct a feature vector . Then i have built my X_train , X_test, y_train , y_test using this feature matrix and then trained my X_train using linear svm and it works . But i have very less accuracy

Comment: @VivekKumar i have one question in my mind that how to make use of svm classifier (what just i did before ) using pipeline . I mean according to the tutorial for which i have referred in the link they use make_pipeline() method  and in that they passed this custom transformer class(feature_extractor) and a classifier (eg svm.LinearSvm()) and when they calls pipe.fit() it just calls the custom class but it should have calls the fit() method of classifier . This is the reason why i am getting no: of col. not to be same in case of both training and testing data .

Comment: @VivekKumarI dont know , i have never clarify this with the author of that blog post . May be you can tell me about this issue

Comment: Pipeline will sequencially call `fit()` and `transform()` to all the methods in it. It `fit()` the data on first class, then transform() the data and then pass to second class. Same ways calls `fit()` and then `transform()` in second class and so on. In the end, it calls the `fit()` method of the last class in the pipe. So in your case it does calls the `svm.fit()`

Comment: @VivekKumar If it calls the svm.fit() then why i am getting this error of not getting same no: of columns of feature vector in both training and testing .Is the fit() method used by svm is that which is defined in my class (feature_extractor) ?, because it can only be possible because of this only . But if we remove these lines " pipe = make_pipeline(my_featurizer,svm.LinearSVC()) , 
pipe.fit(X_train,y_train) , 
pred = pipe.predict(X_test)" and simply called svm.fit() and svm.predit() then it will give answer without any error .